# error in creation of json object from java valueobjects

Tags: java, json, org.json

I am trying to create a json object from my java bean class,  firstly I create a `StringBuffer` and  append the data in it and then convert this `StringBuffer` to String while converting this `String` into json object I am getting this error.

```
org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONException: Expected a ':' after a key at character 129 of {data:{"id":"5345345","name":"dsfsdf","dep":"","ssc":"dgffdgfdg"},{"id":"123456","name":"SBI","dep":"654321","ssc":"State Bank"}}
```

129th is second last letter. is there any syntax problem ?

Comment: I see a syntax error in your JSON, if it was an Array

Comment: yes it is an array of objects

Comment: Do you have any problem in forming the Json as answered below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your data as an Array of objects,

Your JSON should be

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "5345345",
            "name": "dsfsdf",
            "dep": "",
            "ssc": "dgffdgfdg"
        },
        {
            "id": "123456",
            "name": "SBI",
            "dep": "654321",
            "ssc": "State Bank"
        }
    ]
}
```